# How to specify Java Home/JDK in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

With reference to the above-mentioned title, the path has been given at the time of opening SQL Developer for the first time. Now I need to change the path.

Can anyone help me or guide me to do this?

Answer (score 9):

It depends on on your operating system.

Windows:

User, AppData, Roaming Profiles, sqldeveloper, *VERSION*, product.conf

[image]

Note for the Version value: if you're on version 4.0, you'll see 1.0 as the top level directory. After that you should see things like 17.3 or 18.2.

Linux & OS X

$home/.sqldeveloper, product.conf

Open file, update your Java Home.

[image]

Make sure you're pointing to an Oracle Java JDK - we don't support OpenJDK today.

Latest version of SQL Developer expects a Java 8 JDK.

Version 19.2 or higher will also work with 11 or Oracle JDK 12.

Comment: you're very welcome @MohammadSharfuddin - upvotes are always welcome too :)

Answer (score 0):

In the same folder, `Roaming`, delete all older SQL Developer folders. When you upgrade SQL Developer version, Java will first look in these folders.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I browse the java path as

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.8
```

It worked for me, please try it out if you need